# Trying to prove a result about sequencse and series

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ finite, then
>
> $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ a_n x^n }{n!}
>  = L $$

### Try:

we know $a_n x^n = ( \sqrt[n]{a_n} x )^n $. So, we can write the series as exponential

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x} e^{\sqrt[n]{a_n} x} = \lim \frac{e^{x}}{e^{ -\sqrt[n]{a_n} +1} }$$

but, here I am stuck. Is my idea right? or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: I don't see how to make your approach work. Are you familiar with $\epsilon \delta$ proofs?

Comment: Should be summing up all $a_i$ aswell?

Comment: Have you tried pushing e^-x inside and taking a natural log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $N$ be large enough that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ for $n\geq N$. Then
\begin{align}|e^{-x}\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n \frac{x^n}{n!} - L| &=e^{-x}|\sum_{n\geq0} (a_n-L)\frac{x^n}{n!}|\\& =e^{-x}|\sum_{N>n\geq0} (a_n-L)\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n\geq N} (a_n-L)\frac{x^n}{n!}|\\&
\leq e^{-x}|\sum_{N>n\geq0} (a_n-L)\frac{x^n}{n!}|+e^{-x}\sum_{n\geq N} |a_n-L|\frac{x^n}{n!} \\& \leq e^{-x}|\sum_{N>n\geq0} (a_n-L)\frac{x^n}{n!}|+ e^{-x}\epsilon \sum_{n\geq N}\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
&\leq  e^{-x}|\sum_{N>n\geq0} (a_n-L)\frac{x^n}{n!}|+\epsilon.\end{align}
Letting $x \rightarrow \infty$,
$$\limsup_{x\rightarrow \infty}|e^{-x}\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n \frac{x^n}{n!} - L|\leq \epsilon,$$
and finally the result follows by letting $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.